# i have a dataset where the target variable has 15% null values and i want to use those null rows as my test set is it possible?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, linear-regression, isnull

i am using machine learning algorithm linear regression for predicting the values of real estate sale price and keeping the sale price as my target variable .But sale price has 15% null values in it so can i use that 15 % as my test set and the nun-null values as my training set?

Comment: If all training values are null, then null is all that could be learned. If such data perfectly trained a model, that model should always predict null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this but since you dont have the real values for that test set, you will not be able to evaluate the performance of your model. There wont be any ground truth to evaluate against. I would suggest to use non-null data in a 80-10-10 split for train-validatiton-test and check accuracy. If this accuracy is good, then use this model to predict null values and then use the entire non-null data to train and then use that model to predict null data again. Then evaluate the predictions from both and you will have perfect evaluation and results.